# How can I debug in a botman webdriver in laravel?

Tags: laravel, botman

```
-> DD('here');
```

is not working.

```
-> info('incoming', request()->all());
```

did work but for some reason not anymore.

```
-> Log::info('Bot is listening...');
```

did work but for some reason not anymore.

So my bigger problem is that I am debugging the web-driver of botman because my interactive button doesnt work and I am trying to still figure out why. It stopped working after the chat was embedded.

Comment: did you change the `.env` file or `logging.php`? before it stopped working?

Comment: Try writing the desired channel and check `Log::channel('name')->info('Bot is listening...');`

Comment: Hi all , For future references , this works the best ->

    error_log('here');